# Geosparql in Ontop protégé

Tags: postgis, protege, geosparql

I am trying to use geosparql in ontop, protege. I am writing simple queries but i am getting empty results. I didnt import geosparql ontology.

FILTER(geof:sfCrosses(?nodeGeom, ?pipeGeom))

Is this the correct way to use geosparql functions?